# Form validation and captcha

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, captcha

I have two issues with a contact form I have created. I was previously hit hard by spam.

1. I am requiring that all fields be filled out before the form is processed, but what I have written isn't working: info goes into the database whether a person fills out all fields or not. ***fixed by using:

   function validateForm()
    {
    var x=document.forms["validation"]["firstname"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
     {
     alert("Please enter your first name");
     return false;
     }

for all fields and this one for email:

```
    var x=document.forms["validation"]["email"].value;
 var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
 var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
 if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
  alert("Please enter a valid email address");
  return false;
  }
```

Now, I need to get the captcha working or how to add to check if captcha is correct in same javascript? I think the error lies in this somehow?:

```
    session_start();
    if($_POST['submitted'] == "contactus")
     if( $_SESSION['security_code'] == $_POST['security_code'] &&   !empty($_SESSION['security_code'] ) ) {
        header("Location:http://www.berrieswebdesign.com/thankyou.php?message=thanks");
                unset($_SESSION['security_code']);
   } else {
    // Insert your code for showing an error message here
    echo "<div id='thankyoubox'>'Security breach! Security Breach! Ehem...Your     security code was incorrect.'</div>";
  }
    ob_flush();

        ?>
```

And lastly, here is contactfunctions.php

```
    <?php ob_start();//Required for the redirect to work?>
 <?php 
 include_once("databasefunctions.php");

 $contactsdbtable = "contacts";

 function GetHeaders()
 {
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    // Additional headers
    $headers .= "To: {$firstname} <{$email}>" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: My Website <info@mywebsite.com>' . "\r\n";
    return $headers;
 }
 function ContactMessage($firstname, $lastname, $email, $message, $location)
 {
global $contactsdbtable;
openDatabase();
$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($firstname);
$lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($lastname);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($message);
$location = mysql_real_escape_string($location);

$result = QuickQuery("INSERT INTO {$contactsdbtable}(firstname, lastname, email, message, location) 
                      VALUES('{$firstname}', '{$lastname}', '{$email}', '{$message}', '{$location}')");

if($result)
{
    $headers = GetHeaders();
    $message = "\"Thank you for contacting us at My Website. We will be answering your website inquiry post haste.\"<br />
    <br />
    <br />
    Best Regards,<br />
    <br />
    Me
    ";
    mail($email, "RE: Design Inquiry", $message, $headers);
    mail("myemail@blahblah.com", "Website Inquiry", "{$firstname}, {$email}, has sent a web design inquiry", $headers);

}
}


?>
```

I appreciate any help I receive on this in advance. Also, since this is a lengthy post, would you guys mind listing which issue you are addressing, 1 or 2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok try this:

```
<?php
    $is_error = false;
    if($_POST['submitted'] == "contactus")
    {
      $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
      $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $message = $_POST['message'];
      $location = $_POST['location'];
      if(!$firstname || $firstname = ''){
        $error = "Please enter your first name.";
        $is_error = true;
      } else if(!$lastname || $lastname= ''){
        $error = "Please enter your last name.";
        $is_error = true;
      } else if(!$email || $email= ''){
        $error = "Please enter a valid email.";
        $is_error = true;
      }else if(!$message || $message= ''){
        $error = "Please enter your message.";
        $is_error = true;
      }else if(!$location || $location= ''){
        $error = "Please tell us where you're from.";
        $is_error = true;
      }

      if(($is_error === false) && ($_SESSION['security_code'] == $_POST['security_code']))
      {
        ContactMessage($firstname, $lastname, $email, $message, $location);
      } else {
        Error($error);
      }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: thanks Zac. I tried this and skipped adding info into a form field, but the rest of the info still went into the database

Comment: Thanks Zac. Still not working. I have implemented javascript now (courtesy w3 schools) that issues an alert when a field is not filled out. I have tested it and nothing is entering the database until all fields are filled out. But I am still having the captcha issue. Please see revised code above.

Comment: This issued a correct security warning, but when all fields are filled in and the captcha is correct, you get "Thanks for contacting us," but nothing goes into the database. Also, none of the error messages are showing when a field is left out